# `__ge__` fails when used on dict.values()

Tags: python

I create a dictionary,

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'f': 6}
```

when I use `dir` on its values,

```
print(dir(d.values()))
```

it gives,

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',
 '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

but how exactly is the `__ge__` supposed to be used? (and similarly, `__gt__`, `__le__`, ...)
as when I do,

```
e = {'w': 5, 'x': 6, 'y': 7, 'z': 8}
print(d.values() >= e.values())
```

it gives,

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'
```

similar error appears if I compare `dict_values` with `dict` or `set` or `list` or ...

carrying a similar experiment with `d.keys()` gives a result,

```
print(d.keys() >= e.keys())
```

gives,

```
False
```

and if I change,

```
e = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

```
print(d.keys() >= e.keys())
```

gives,

```
False
```

but should it not raise an error, comparing string to int, and furthermore, `len(d.keys())` is not equal to `len(e.keys())`?

Comment: You are comparing two lists of integer values, testing if one of the lists is "greater than" the other.  That doesn't really make sense conceptually.  What is it that you are really trying to accomplish?  In your mind, what does it mean to ask if `[1, 2, 3, 6]` is "greater than or equals to" `[5, 6, 7, 8]`?  My guess is that whatever you want to do should involve operating on the individual values in each list, like for example, comparing the first value of each list, then the second, etc.  Your question should be easy to answer once it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: _"but how exactly is the `__ge__` supposed to be used"_ could you elaborate on why you expect it to be used? All normal objects (even `object()`) have those methods to support the comparison protocol. When comparisons can't be meaningfully made, those methods return `NotImplemented`, which is what you're observing here. _"but should [comparing dict_keys instances] not raise an error, comparing string to int,"_ I don't follow this reasoning. Would you expect `{1,2} == {"a", "b"}` to raise a TypeError?

Comment: You're just seeing the default implementations from object via dir, which per your output raises an error. What were you expecting to do with that comparison?

Comment: @CryptoFool they're _not_ lists in Python 3, they're views: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists (and you _can_ compare lists).

Comment: @CryptoFool What? There's no list comparisons here. And besides,  whether 'one of the lists is "greater than" the other' can be [a well defined notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

Comment: guys, I don't think he's trying to argue about a reason for using >= between dict_values. I believe the question here is: Why **can** I compare dict_keys (and not values) and what does this comparison return

Comment: The reason for the existence of `__ge__` and the like on those kinds of objects is so that it can tell you it's not supported, overriding what would otherwise be inherited behavior.

Comment: @Brian - We're talking semantics here.  I was using the term "list" loosely to convey a concept rather than to get down to the implementation (hence my use of the word "conceptually").  I was looking to better understand the OP's desired end result.  It seems that the question was more about the specifics of the observed behavior rather than a desired outcome.  That being the case, I'm glad to see that the answers to the question seem to address this quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main reasoning is what is mentioned in the docs under [Dictionary View Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

Now the documentation for collections.abc.Set didn't really explain anything beyond mentioning which operations are supported, so I looked to the [dictobject.c source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c) . `dictview_richcompare` is the place where the operations are defined for Dictionary Views, and after some type and edge case the main logic relies on length of both views and whether one is contained in (i.e. subset of) the other:

```
ok = 0;
    switch(op) {

    case Py_NE:
    case Py_EQ:
        if (len_self == len_other)
            ok = all_contained_in(self, other);
        if (op == Py_NE && ok >= 0)
            ok = !ok;
        break;

    case Py_LT:
        if (len_self < len_other)
            ok = all_contained_in(self, other);
        break;

      case Py_LE:
          if (len_self <= len_other)
              ok = all_contained_in(self, other);
          break;

    case Py_GT:
        if (len_self > len_other)
            ok = all_contained_in(other, self);
        break;

    case Py_GE:
        if (len_self >= len_other)
            ok = all_contained_in(other, self);
        break;

    }
```

```
/* Return 1 if self is a subset of other, iterating over self;
   0 if not; -1 if an error occurred. */
static int
all_contained_in(PyObject *self, PyObject *other)
```

Where the `PyTypeObject` for keys, values and items are defined `dictview_richcompare` is passed for `PyDictKeys_Type` and `PyDictItems_Type`, but `0` is passed for `PyDictValues_Type`. So it's not even plugged into the same comparison method as the other two views.

I couldn't really find any comments in the file about *why* values was excluded, so I'm assuming it is again related to the "unique and hashable" properties mentioned in the docs. Even intuitively, it wouldn't really make much sense to compare values on the basis of subsets without their keys.

Comment: Nice, I haven't had the time to look in the source code (but it confirms what I guessed the set operators do in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `d.values().__gt__.__qualname__`, it says `'object.__gt__'`. So it is probably the same as `object().__gt__`, which I guess the only thing it does is that it returns `NotImplemented` (which in turn raises an error about uncomparable types). See this example:

```py
In [31]: d.values().__gt__(object())
Out[31]: NotImplemented

In [32]: d.values() > object()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-59ecc977c231> in <module>
----> 1 d.values() > object()

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'object'
```

However `dict_keys` overrides this behavior, as you can see on `d.keys().__gt__.__qualname__` which returns `'dict_keys.__gt__'`.

As you can find in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), `dict_keys` are dictionary view objects that act like a set (and sets are defined with comparison operations). For example, set `A` is greater than `B` if `B` is a strict subset of `A`.

For example:

```py
In [1]: A = set()
In [2]: B = set()

In [3]: A > B
Out[3]: False

In [4]: A >= B
Out[4]: True

In [5]: A.add(3)

In [6]: A > B
Out[6]: True

In [7]: A.add(4); B.add(3)

In [8]: A > B
Out[8]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Well looking at the python source code, it seems that comparison between `dict_keys` is called `dictview_richcompare` in the class [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L5112) and the code is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L4642), so you see that comparison between keys only takes the length in consideration. Also, if you take a look at `dict_vals` [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L5274) you will see that `tp_richcompare` is not implemented! Which solves the  mistery.